# How to pass HTML Table Data to cgi and c++

Tags: javascript, c++, cgi, command-line-arguments, html-table

This is my html code . I want to pass the table data to my CGI script using c++.

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Ex. Date</th>
        <th>Security<br /> Symbol</th>
        <th>Factor</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>29/01/1993</td>
            <td>uaasset</td>
            <td>333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11/06/1995</td>
            <td>ibm</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div><br />

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
```

Here with i have posted my CGI code.

```
char *data;
char* lpszContentLength;
int nContentLength;

lpszContentLength = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");   
if(lpszContentLength == NULL)   
   return -1;       
nContentLength = atoi(lpszContentLength);
if(nContentLength == 0) 
data = (char*) malloc(nContentLength+1);    
if(data == NULL)    
  return -1;
memset(data, 0, nContentLength+1);  
if(fread(data, 1, nContentLength, stdin) == 0)  // get the data
    return -1;

if(ferror(stdin))   // die if there was an fread error
  return -1;

   cout << data<<"<br>";
```

Now i didn't receive any data to my cgi . Why i can't pass the table data to cgi. I'm thinking to pass the table data from javascript . But I don't know how to call cgi script using javascript and how to pass the data to cgi from javascript. I need to store the table data to my TextFile. Is there any idea to implement this in cgi & c++ ?

Comment: you need to use `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest`for this

Answer (score 0):

With html you cannot post a table tag because it just a output to do in HTML web pages you should post the data in form submit.

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('hdnFormField').value = document.getElementById('tblData').innerHTML;" >
    <table id="tblData">
        ...yourTable..
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnFormField" id="hdnFormField" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

and on the back and you should read `Request.Form["hdnFormField"]`. Sorry I don t know how read in in cgi.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP support 2 different ways to pass data to page: GET and POST.

GET:
when browser open url: http://example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2
To your cgi script will be put such data: param1 => value, param2 => value2. To get this data from C you can get them from environment:

```
char* val1 = getenv("param1");
char* val2 = getenv("param2");
```

POST:
Post -> browser send all data in http request body. All data, that send to cgi goes throught stdin.

```
char Buffer[512]={0}; 
int InputLength = atoi( getenv("INPUT_LENGTH") ); 
InputLength = min( InputLength, sizeof(Buffer)-1 ); /* Avoid buffer overflow */ 
fread( Buffer, InputLength, 1, stdin );
```

Javascript:
GET: Send get request very simple. If you use jQuery and want send GET request via ajax use such code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/yourpage.cgi?param1=value1&param2=value2',
});
```

POST:

```
$.post("/yourpage.cgi", { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" } );
```

Good luck ;-)

Comment: Also, you have idea problem. You can't pass "table data" to cgi. Browser send data only data, that in "input" html tag. 

<form method="post">
  .. some html here
  <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

Comment: Good Info. But i don't wanna use Ajax and Jquery. But i tried this code. Working fine. I implemented it with JavaScript also.